# Adding "Calendar Type" field to "Insert Date and Time" Dialog Box

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-word

My wife got a new computer at her work, and I set it up with all of the software she had on the old machine. The old machine was a single core Intel Celeron running Windows 7 Home Premium. Her new machine is an Intel an i3 running Windows Ultimate. We got the language toolbar installed with the Hebrew Keyboard.

She uses Microsoft Office 2003, and we installed it on her new machine too. In Microsoft Word on her old system, if she selected ***Insert->Date and Time***, it brought up the *Date and Time* dialog box with both a *Language* and a  *Calendar Type* field. On her new machine, selecting ***Insert->Date and Time*** brings up a *Date and Time* dialog box without the *Calendar Type* field.

How can I get, so she's able to insert the Hebrew Lunar date?

[image: Dialog Box with Both Fields]

[image: Dialog Box allowing inserting Hebrew Lunar Date and Time]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing these steps make sure all office programs are closed (this may or may not be necessary).

1. Go to **Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language**
2. Click **Add a language**
3. Select **Hebrew**
4. Click **Add**

Comment: I just had my wife try this. Hebrew is already added to **Control Panel->All Control Panel Items->Language**. I'll go over there and make sure all office programs are closed and try this again, though.

Comment: We had to reboot after adding Hebrew as a language, and that solved the problem.